# Is it possible to save only SOME parts of a nested form to the DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a nested form that takes "brand" "model" "submodel" and "style" ... Now, there are multiple styles for any given brand+model+submodel combination.. but I don't want to re-save the same brand name (or model or submodel) twice in my database..

So, given the above situation, what would I need to do in my CREATE action in my controller to ensure that brand names in the db are unique.. etc.. but so that the nested form can still be submitted?

Also, the saved 'style' would need to adopt the submodel id from an existing submodel object, if one (with the same submodel name) is already listed in the submodel table.

UPDATE:

[image]

I would like to allow my nested form to save x y and z, and have the following:

Panasonic (not saved, but the ID is read out and saved with model x as brand_id)
X (saved with brand_id from Panasonic)
Y (saved with model_id from model X)
Z (saved with submodel_id from Y)

Of course if Model X already exists then I would like

Panasonic (not saved)
X (not saved)
Y (saved with X's ID as model_id)
Z (saved with Ys new ID as submodel_id)

You see where I'm going with this?  =)

Answer (score 0):

If i under stand your question correctly, you have something like a product model that has attributes brand, model (should name this something else), submodel, styles.  I would do this by creating the following models:

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

class Primodel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  has_many :submodels
end

class Submodel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

class Style < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

class ProductsStyles < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :style
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :primodel
  belongs_to :submodel
  belongs_to :brand
  has_many :products_styles
  has_many :styles, :through => :products_styles
end
```

This should allow you to create and reuse brands, models, submodels, and styles.  It would restrict each product to only having one of each of the first three but allow you to have multiple styles.

Comment: Ben, thanks for the comment. Perhaps I wasn't as clear as I should have been. Please see my update. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is what I needed to do:

```
@brand1 = params[:brand][:name]
@model = params[:brand][:models_attributes]["0"]["name"]
@submodel = params[:brand][:models_attributes]["0"]["submodels_attributes"]["0"]["name"]
@style = params[:brand][:models_attributes]["0"]["submodels_attributes"]["0"]["styles_attributes"]["0"]["name"]

a = Brand.find_or_create_by_name(@brand1)
b = Model.find_or_create_by_name(@model, :brand_id => a.id)
c = Submodel.find_or_create_by_name(@submodel, :model_id => b.id)
d = Style.new(:name => @style, :submodel_id => c.id)
d.save
```